# relationship between expectation of a ratio of random variables and a ratio of expectation of random variables

Tags: regression, probability, expected-value, ratio

I know that in general for random variables $X$ and a function $g$

$E[g(X)]\ne g[E(X)]$.

I would like to know when the following holds

$E_Z\Big[\frac{cov(X,Y|Z)}{var(X|Z)}\Big] = \frac{E_Z[cov(X,Y|Z)]}{E_Z[var(X|Z)]}$.

Clearly it holds if $X$ and $Z$ are independent.
I have also been able to show that it holds if $Y$ is a linear function of $X$ and $Z$ (with or without linear interaction).

So I would like to know if there might be a more general condition under which it holds.

I ask because frequently when I do proof in the context mosty of regression I get one or the other form and would like to know when I can use this as an equality.

Of note is you can derive the value of $\beta_1$ given $E(Y|X,Z)=\beta_0+\beta_1X+\beta_2Z$ in one way that gives one of these and in another way that gives the other (which is how I know in this case the equality must hold).

Comment: Covariance and variance are constants. Unless I’m missing something (it’s happened before), I would say that the equality holds whenever those covariance variance values exist.

Comment: @Dave While covariance and variance are constants, these_conditional_ covariances and conditional variances are _functions_ of $Z$, the _conditioning_ random variable, and thus themselves are random variables. The question is thus of the form "When does $E\left[\dfrac{g(Z)}{h(Z)}\right]$ equal $\dfrac{E[g(Z)]}{E[h(Z)]}??$"

Comment: And now it’s happened again!